# Failed to get broadcast_1_piece0 of broadcast_1 in Spark Streaming job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, bigdata

I am running spark jobs on yarn in cluster mode. The job get the messages from kafka direct stream. I am using broadcast variables and checkpointing every 30 seconds. When I start the job first time it runs fine without any issue. If I kill the job and restart it throws below exception in executor upon receiving a message from kafka:

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_1_piece0 of broadcast_1
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1178)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at net.juniper.spark.stream.LogDataStreamProcessor$2.call(LogDataStreamProcessor.java:177)
    at net.juniper.spark.stream.LogDataStreamProcessor$2.call(LogDataStreamProcessor.java:1)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone have idea how to resolve this error?

Spark version: 1.5.0

CDH 5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

When encountering issues where only the first run works, it always resulted in issues revolving the checkpoint data. Moreover, the use of checkpoints only happens when there is something to check, which is the first message from kafka.
I suggest you check if you the job is indeed dead, that is, maybe the process is still running on the machine that executed it.
try running a simple `ps -fe` and see if something is still running. if there are 2 processes trying to use the same checkpoint folder, it will always fail.
hope this helps

Comment: I have checked, the job was not dead. I am running three sparks job and created checkpoint directories /tmp/spark/<job1>, /tmp/spark<job2>, /tmp/spark/<job3>. If I delete the checkpoint directories and then start the job then it runs without any issue. Most probably, it is unable to initialize the broadcast variables from checkpointed data.

Comment: not sure I understand. it seems that the issue is that when you stop the job it is not killed and the process keep running. a workaround would be to just create a script that kill the process as well as stop the job. am I missing something?

Comment: sorry for typo, in my earlier comment, I wanted to mention that the job was dead, I had verified that.